# boto instance.__dict__['tags']['Name'] output issue

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, instance, boto

**UPDATE:**

---

**I did what was suggested below, however, I was still getting an KeyError:'Name' in the output, even though the output was correct.**

This was the output:

```
us-west-1 EC2Connection:
ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com 
Showing all of your current instances 
Proxy-44-1000-Enrollments 
Proxy-45-1000-Enrollments 
Proxy-48-1000-Enrollments 
Proxy-49-1000-Enrollments 
Proxy-59-1000-Enrollments 
Proxy-67-1000-Enrollments 

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/xxxxx/xxxx/boto/instanceid.py", 
line 43, in <module> print "\t%s" % (instance.tags['Name']) if instance.state ==
'running' else instance.state KeyError: 'Name'
```

---

**Initial Question:**

I'm trying to dump out a list of Instance ID's along with their "Name" tag from AWS using boto.  I found online a method that one can attach to the instance object, called `__dict__`, which seemed to work well, however, I wanted to pull out the "name" tag only when using this method, but I keep getting an error "Key Error:'Name'"

Basically, this code works:

```py
# Creating connection object to EC2
conn = boto.connect_ec2()

regions = boto.ec2.regions()

# the 5 element in the array is "us-west-1" and setting the object to connect
us = regions[5]
print us.name
conn_us = us.connect()
print conn_us

filters = {'key-name' : 'misc-key'}

all_inst = conn_us.get_all_instances(filters=filters)

print "Showing all of your current instances" 
for res in all_inst: 
    # each reservation have a instance: 
    for instance in res.instances: 
        print "\t%s: \t%s" % (instance.id, instance.__dict__['tags'])
```

The output is hoky tho:

```
us-west-1
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Showing all of your current instances
    i-xxxxxxxx:     {u'Name': u'Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments'}
    i-xxxxxxxx:     {u'Name': u'Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments'}
    i-xxxxxxxx:     {u'Name': u'Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments'}
    i-xxxxxxxx:     {u'Name': u'Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments'}
    i-xxxxxxxx:     {u'Name': u'Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments'}
```

When I make a change to the `__dict__` method to "pull" out "name" only, it works (or seems to work, but throws an error:

Here is the code change:

```py
print "\t%s: \t%s" % (instance.id, instance.__dict__['tags']['Name'])
```

Here is the output:

```
us-west-1
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Showing all of your current instances
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments
    i-xxxxxxxx:     Proxy-xx-1000-Enrollments

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxxx/xxx.xxx/boto/instanceid.py", line 43, in <module>
    print "\t%s: \t%s" % (instance.id, instance.__dict__['tags']["Name"])
KeyError: 'Name'
```

I prefer this output, **WITHOUT** the error - can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Why not just access the tags attribute directly?  Getting to it via `__dict__` is not very pythonic:

```
instance.tags['Name']
```

You also might want to look at the state of the instance since some of the instances in the Reservation objects that you get back from get_all_instances() may be recently terminated instances.  You could report the name on only the running instances and the state otherwise (NOTE - this .state check is just an idea to show the `A if cond else B` syntax.  You will still have to play with it on your own):

```
instance.tags['Name'] if instance.state == 'running' else instance.state
```

You can use [`dict.get()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) if all you want to do is avoid the KeyError and return a default value.

```
instance.tags.get('Name')  
# or with a default
instance.tags.get('Name', '--')
```

Here is a blurb pulled from the [boto ec2 tutorial](http://boto.s3.amazonaws.com/ec2_tut.html) that mentions Reservation objects and instance state.

> If you just want to get a list of all of your running instances, use
>   the get_all_instances method of the connection object. Note that the
>   list returned is actually a list of Reservation objects (which contain
>   the Instances) and that the list may include recently terminated
>   instances for a small period of time subsequent to their termination.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, really appreciate it.  However, when I use your syntax, I'm still getting the "KeyError" when running the updated code:

Comment: `us-west-1
EC2Connection:ec2.us-west-1.amazonaws.com
Showing all of your current instances
 Proxy-44-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-45-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-48-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-49-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-59-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-67-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-70-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-71-1000-Enrollments
 Proxy-73-1000-Enrollments
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/xxxxx/xxxx/boto/instanceid.py", line 43, in <module>
    print "\t%s" % (instance.tags['Name']) if instance.state == 'running' else instance.state
KeyError: 'Name'`